# Will Android PackageManager accept an app claiming systemOrSignature permission?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-package-managers

If a non-system app requests for a permission defined at systemOrSignature protection level, will Android PackageManager reject the app at install time or will it install the app successfully and just ignore the permission?

Answer (score 1):

The app will be installed but a [`SecurityException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/SecurityException.html) will be thrown if you use a permission the system cannot grant. You can read more about permissions here: [System Permissions | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html)